# How to target NHibernate.IQueryOver<T>.List using Resharper's external annotations?

Tags: annotations, resharper

I'm in love with Resharper's external annotation (`NotNull`, `CanBeNull`, ...) and would like to add some to certain NHibernate methods. I'm currently trying to annotate the two methods `NHiberate.IQueryOver<T>.List()` and `NHibernate.IQueryOver<T>.List<U>()` with `NotNull`, but unable to get Resharper to use my annotations.

I'm currently trying to generate annotations for NHibernate using the built-in (internal) tool Annotator, at pass 62, and no way to know how many passes are required, or if it will provide me with any clues.

Attempts so far, stored in `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\v7.1\Bin\ExternalAnnotations\NHibernate\NHibernate.NotNull.xml`. I'm basically guessing.

```
<assembly name="NHibernate">
    <member name="M:NHibernate.IQueryOver`1.List">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />
    </member>

    <member name="M:NHibernate.IQueryOver`1.List()">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />
    </member>

    <member name="M:NHibernate.IQueryOver``1.List">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />
    </member>

    <member name="M:NHibernate.IQueryOver``1.List()">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />
    </member>

    <member name="M:NHibernate.IQueryOver`1.List`1">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />
    </member>

    <member name="M:NHibernate.IQueryOver`1.List`1()">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />
    </member>

    <member name="M:NHibernate.IQueryOver``1.List`1">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />
    </member>

    <member name="M:NHibernate.IQueryOver``1.List`1()">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />
    </member>

    <member name="M:NHibernate.IQueryOver`1.List``1">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />
    </member>

    <member name="M:NHibernate.IQueryOver`1.List``1()">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />
    </member>

    <member name="M:NHibernate.IQueryOver``1.List``1">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />
    </member>

    <member name="M:NHibernate.IQueryOver``1.List``1()">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />
    </member>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Have you tried placing the annotations in `ExternalAnnotations\Misc\NHibernate\NHibernate.NotNull.xml`? I believe it's Anything\AssemblyName\Anything.xml. You can quickly check if annotations are applied or not via QuickDoc on the member (Ctrl-Q or Ctrl-Shift-F1)

Comment: @IgalTabachnik, the location is correct. I've answered by own question with the correct annotation (and waiting until I can accept it). It's applied correctly in it's current location. I guess I had some odd whitespace or xml parsing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to say exactly where the problem is, but I basically created mockup interfaces with identical declarations, generated xmldoc and copied the generated method definitions into the annotation xml. I also redid the complete annotation file starting with a blank xml file.

```
<assembly name="NHibernate">
    <member name="M:NHibernate.IQueryOver`1.List">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />
    </member>

    <member name="M:NHibernate.IQueryOver`1.List``1">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />
    </member>
</assembly>
```

My above try-everything-approach should have matched, but didn't. I guess there were some issues with whitespaces or just bad luck.